# reading CSV error: Illegal Data. What's happening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, jquery-csv

I'm having the following error, and I have no idea what's going on...

Here is the first row in my csv file (I opened it using vim)

```
longitude,latitude,ph,ammonium_nitrate,phosphate,permanganate,heavy_metal,email_address^M
```

Here is the error I see in my safari console:

```
[Error] Error: CSVDataError: Illegal Data [Row:1][Col:8]
(anonymous function) (jquery-csv-0.71.js, line 253)
replace
parse (jquery-csv-0.71.js, line 160)
toArrays (jquery-csv-0.71.js, line 664)
success (demo.html, line 64)
c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js, line 4)
fireWith (jquery-1.10.2.min.js, line 4)
k (jquery-1.10.2.min.js, line 6)
r (jquery-1.10.2.min.js, line 6)
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see an extra Carriage Return in the line. The ^M thing. remove and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file appears to be imported from a windows box (due to the presence of the ^M character). If you are working with this file in linux your parser may not like it. Remove the ^M from your file.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. should I replace it with \n? how should I separate each line?

Comment: BTW, 0.81 should be able to handle any variation of newline characters without issue. FYI, I'm the author of jquery-csv.

Comment: Hi @EvanPlaice I am using jquery csv and I get [Error] Error: CSVDataError: Illegal Data whenever someone edit file in some other operating system. When I re-edit the file the error get resolved. Can you suggest a solution so that end user does not get this error?

Comment: @EvanPlaice can you please mention a link to jquery csv 0.81? Thanks.